# What was the longest Rocketdyne F-1 full power test?

Tags: reuse, f1

This number is relevant to the issue of F-1 reusability, as it determines how many flights are required before serious work needs to be done. That is because LOX/Kerosene engines have coking problems that can clog the engine after enough time.

I understand that the F-1 was rated for an accumulated 2250 seconds. But I'm told that given the limits of test stands, this was done over multiple firings, between which extensive cleaning of coke deposits, as well as other work, may have been done.

But I do not know what the capacity of these stands were. If they were comparable to the stages that the engines flew with, and I would expect no less, they must have been able to supply enough fuel for 840 seconds of firing. So what was the length of the longest full power test firing?

Comment: Can't find a definitive answer, but in addition to 140-second "full duration" runs referred to in [Stages To Saturn](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/sp4206.htm), there's mention of June 1972 tests of an F-1 taken out of storage: *The engine was run through two extended duration firings at Edwards Air Force Base, then subjected to rigorous inspection and analysis. The engine showed no abnormalities.* The footnote cites a 1972 edition of the Marshall Star (NASA MSFC's newsletter, I think?), but I can't find that online.

Comment: "Remembering the Giants" talks about 165 s engine tests and 125 s stage tests.

Comment: Is your "840 seconds" a typo? The Saturn V first stage fired for only about 150 seconds.

Comment: @RussellBorogove that's when burning five engines.

Comment: Coking is more related to the number of firing cycles, not to total firing time. Coking (the conversion of short-chain hydrocarbons to large molecular weight soot) occurs when fuel is exposed to temperatures above 600C. This is particularly a problem when RP-1 is used to regeneratively cool the engine bell, as in the F-1. During firing, the flow of fuel cools the bell. At shut-down, flow stops but latent heat continues to heat the remaining fuel in the cooling tubes. An analogy is the way automobiles can boil over if shut down after a hard run without a period of cool-down running Coking would

Comment: The engines were cleaned after each test using a lot of tetrachloroethyelene which polluted the soil below.

Comment: @Woody so essentially if you could keep fuel flowing a bit longer after shutdown, there would be no coking?

Comment: @Abdullah ... Interesting point. This would have a mass cost in flight, but could reduce maintenance costs for test bed firing. I wonder if they do a "cool down lap" on test engines. Consider posting a question?